# How to make FrameLayout focusable?

Tags: android

My `FrameLayout` have few `EditText`s and I want them to drop focus when I'm touching `FrameLayout`. Is that possible and how?

I'm tried to set `android:focusable` to `true`, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what I've done it's required to call `requestFocus()` on `FrameLayout`.